# How to validate greater than, less than in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

Back again with another absolute beginner question. I'm validating a form, and I want the text input to be limited to more than 2 and less than 15 characters. I have tried:

```
function validateForm(formElement) {
var valid = true;
if (formElement.first_name.value.length < 2) return focusElement(formElement.first_name, 'Please enter a First Name that is more than 2 characters long.');
if (formElement.first_name.value.length > 15) return focusElement(formElement.first_name, 'Please enter a First Name that is less than 15 characters long.');
```

As well as

```
if (formElement.first_name.value.length < 2 && formElement.first_name.value.length > 15) return focusElement(formElement.first_name, 'Please enter a First Name that is more than 2 and less than 15 characters long.');
```

Both resulting in errors. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "resulting in errors" -- what errors?

Comment: The first logic should work, so the error is likely with `focusElement(formElement.first_name, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logic issue here - the length can't be less than 2 AND greater than 15. What you're should be using is less than 2 OR greater than 15:

```
if (formElement.first_name.value.length < 2 || formElement.first_name.value.length > 15) return focusElement(formElement.first_name, 'Please enter a First Name that is more than 2 and less than 15 characters long.');
```

I'm also not sure what you're using the `valid = true` variable for here

Comment: It fixes the logic error in the second version of OP's code, but since OP's first version "results in errors", this isn't going fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Wow I feel incredibly stupid!!! //There's a logic issue here - the length can't be less than 2 AND greater than 15//

Answer (score 0):

Your second validation code is incorrect.

Nothing could be <2 and at the same time >15.

You should use 'OR' `||` operation in between, NOT 'AND' `&&`.

What is `FocusElement`. Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Which error did you get? I think FocusElement is your user-defined function. I test your code like following and it's ok.

```
<form name="frm">
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <input type="button" onClick="validateForm(frm)" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I use your validateForm function and write FocusElement javascript function as follow.

```
function focusElement(control,message)
{
   control.focus();
   alert(message);
}
```

And if you want to use second validation code, you should use || instead of &&.